# Validacion de valor DateTime y estado para DatagridView C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, timer

Estoy programando un codigo con c# que lo meti en el `Form Load` que indicaria lo siguiente:

Si pasaron  40 minutos o mas desde que se cargo la venta, y ademas, el estado de la venta no es 1 (Finalizada) o 2 (Cancelada) que me aparezca un `Messagebox` diciendo que tengo un venta demorada:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)


            {
                DateTime FechaVenta = Convert.ToDateTime(fila.Cells[1].Value);
                int EstadoVenta = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[2].Value);
                DateTime FechaVentaMas40Min = FechaVenta.AddMinutes(40);

                if (FechaVenta >= FechaVentaMas40Min && EstadoVenta > 2)
                {
                  MessageBox.Show("Tienes una venta demorada", 
                                  "Atención", 
                                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo deberia poner en realidad? Porque  no me esta funcionando

Comment: Deberias usar un Timer, que su evento se lance a los 40 minutos y ahi verificas y te sale el alerta.

Answer (score 0):

Estas evaluando "FechaVenta >= FechaVentaMas40Min".
En este caso FechaVenta siempre será menor a la FechaVentaMas40Min, porque estableciste que FechaVentaMas40Min es 40 minutos mayor a la FechaVenta.

La evaluación debería ser:

DateTime Ahora = DateTime.Now;

if (Ahora >= FechaVentaMas40Min && EstadoVenta > 2)
{...